# wildcard cert gives Cannot construct a X509SigningCredentials instance for a certificate without the private key from remote server

Tags: iis, certificate, adfs

Windows 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5. Wildcard certificate...which is working on other servers.

We have imported the certificate and used the utility to correct the private key.  The certificate shows that it has a valid private key.

We are using AD FS and trying to add this server.  When accessing the data via https://serverdnshere/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml we get html 500 and the error...Cannot construct a X509SigningCredentials instance for a certificate without the private key.

Not sure what we've missed.  Any pointers would be helpful.

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

All done here.  We were looking at the wrong certificate.